# Resolving Module Not Found error in PythonAnywhere

Tags: automation

I’m trying to automate this Twitter Bot to post daily and I’m using the module Tweepy. Whenever I run it from my terminal, it works fine. Whenever I use the Bash console in PythonAnywhere, it also works fine. I enter “pip install tweepy” before running each code, so the module is already loaded. However, when I just click “Run” in PythonAnywhere, it tries to execute it without tweepy and returns a module not found error. Since, the default for automated code in PythonAnywhere is just the “Run” command, this means it gets an error anytime the bot tries to post automatically. Any tips on how to resolve this? Is there a different website I could use to host/automate the code?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have installed the module into the version of Python that you are running your code with. python in a console runs Python 2.7 and pip installs into Python 2.7. It is very unlikely on PythonAnywhere that the Run button is running Python 2.7. If you have a fairly new account, it's more likely to be Python 3.8. There is a help page on the PythonAnywhere help pages that covers how to run a specific version of Python using the run button.